# querying on json data | Mongodb | django | python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I want to get all the news that are published on dates after Mon, 06 Jun 2016 13:54:32. I tried this:

```
db.collection.find({'date':{$gt:'Mon, 06 Jun 2016 13:54:32'}})
```

but I got an invalid syntax error.

Comment: first issue is you are using single quotation marks. (') instead of ("). and secondly you are missing one braces at the end

Answer (score 0):

**Seems to be a syntax error. Check below code :**

```
db.collection.find({"date":{$gt:"Mon, 06 Jun 2016 13:54:32"}})
```

If you are **connecting from python/django code** , above query might not work again. Use below then:

```
db.collection.find({"date":{"$gt":"Mon, 06 Jun 2016 13:54:32"}})
```

Also see how you are storing the date, if it is in **ISO format**, then use:

```
db.collection.find({"date":{$gt:ISODate("Mon, 06 Jun 2016 13:54:32")}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

`db.collection.find({"date" : { $gt : "Mon, 06 Jun 2016 13:54:32" }});`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do something like $gt: new Date("Mon, 06 Jun 2016 13:54:32Z"), or ISODate(...) to allow mongodb to compare it to the BSON representation it has stored.

Answer (score 0):

its a syntax error.

You write like this 
db.collectionName.find({"AttributeName":{$gt:"You Date Format"}});
In Your Case it should like this 
db.collection.find({"date":{$gt:"Mon, 06 Jun 2016 13:54:32"}})